# schema evolution along with message transformations using confluent_kafka and schema-registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I need to transform messages along with schema evolution to target MySQL DB. I can't use Sink connector here because it supports schema evolution but not complex transformations.

I have a table in MySQL Source like below :

```
id, name, created_at
1, shoaib, 2022-01-01
2, ahmed, 2022-02-01
```

In target MySQL I want to replicate that table with some transformations. Target table would look like

```
id, name, created_at, isDeleted
1, shoaib, 2022-01-01, 0
2, ahmed, 2022-02-01, 0
```

Whenever a row gets deleted in Source, here isDeleted column should be updated as 1.
This is a very simple transformation I just put in.
So, I decided not to use Sink's SMT because it offers very basic transformations. I went with
`confluent_kafka libray` using Python.

I am able to transform data as needed and load into target MySQL but I am not able to make the relevant schema changes automatically to target using `schema-registry` with `confluent_kafka libray`. Schema versions are getting updated in the registry but how to propagate that changes to target DB if I'm not using the Sink connector.

Answer (score 0):

> propagate that changes to target DB if I'm not using the Sink connector

You would need to run an `ALTER TABLE` statement on your own.

I suggest looking at the [Debezium docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html#_configuration) on how it can insert a `__deleted` attribute into the data from the source connector, then you should be able to use an SMT to convert the boolean into an `INT` (or just keep the database having a boolean column rather than a number)

Or you can use Python to write a new schema to a new Kafka topic (creating a new subject in the registry), which then can be consumed by the Sink connector and write to (and evolve) the table.